# php and url rewrites

Tags: php, url-rewriting

so I was wondering if something like this is at all possible.

I was hoping to change `/?directory=$variable` to something like `/$variable`

An actual example might be easier to understand. So I want `<a href='/{$variable}' >` to really be `/?directory=$variable` or in url rewite terms i guess `/?page=$1`

I hope this makes sense. I am really no good with rewriting. Is this even possible? I was hoping to exclude index.php on that. however if that cannot be done, and example with index.php?ect.. will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possibile if your server/hosting supports it you can do it by creating an `.htaccess` file with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /?directory=$1 [L]
```

If you want to allow other directories/files to get accessed normally you should do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /?directory=$1 [L]
```

This will capture any subdirectory like `/abc` but not `/css.css` or `/customsub/other file`

Welcome to the world of SEO optimizer lol.

Comment: this will mess up assets like css,js

Comment: @lawrenece: it doesnt' seem to be a problem for the OP anyway I added some infos

Comment: I was actually hoping for an answer specific to my situation. I understand how url rewriting wirks, just not sure how to do it in this fassion when im not using index.php? and instead /?

Comment: Got it. Idk I just cant seem to get it to work. So my link is as follows `<a href="/$var">` which should translate to `/?directory=$var` correct? it just doe not work, and instead takes me to the directory.

Comment: Try to remove the `/` after `^` `RewriteRule ^([`. If this doesnt' work it could be because you actually don't have mod_rewrite loaded

Comment: That does not seem to work either. I do have mod_rewrite enabled as I am using rewrites elsewhere successfully. Maybe ill have to look into cUrl for this one? and just post the info over the url.

Comment: @jason: no. try to remove the slash to `/?directory=$1` otherwise try to point to another file and see if it works. something like `tester.php?id=$1`

Comment: hmm.. whats interesting is it actually goes into the directory, and THEN adds the get data to the url. eample`http://domain.com/mysqli/?directory=mysqli`

Comment: Ill look into it. thanks for the help though. However one last question. what if i DO want to rewrite `/$var` to `index.php?directories=$var` ? I think this may avoid another issue im having

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /index.php?directory=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewriting is done on the Web Server (Apache, IIS, etc.) and not within a scripting language like PHP.

If you are using Apache, check this out:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Actually it can be done with PHP, you just need to handle 404 errors with `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?directory=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This displays my info correctly however the url is not correct. it shows `http://domain.com/mysqli/?directory=mysqli` when it should just be `http://domain.com/mysqli/`

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: although this is true, in the tutorial it doesn't explain having `example.com/variable` only `example.com/cat/variable` or `example.com/variable/`